# How do I use the InvertedVisibility binding on MVVM cross iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to achieve:

I want my button only to be visible when Bytes is null, i.e., before I have taken a picture.

I have tried the following:

```
set.Bind (btnTakePhoto).For("Visibility").To(x => x.Bytes).WithConversion("InvertedVisibility");
```

and

```
set.Bind (btnTakePhoto).For("InvertedVisibility").To(x => x.Bytes).WithConversion("InvertedVisibility");
```

and

```
set.Bind (btnTakePhoto).For("InvertedVisibility").To(x => x.Bytes).WithConversion("Visibility");
```

and a couple of other variations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do it is

```
set.Bind (btnTakePhoto)
.For("Visibility")
.To(x => x.Bytes)
.WithConversion("InvertedVisibility");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not set the visibility when the value is null. Bind it to a new boolean property associated with your Bytes, and in the setter of Bytes call OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsTakePhotoVisible)) like this:

viewmodel:

```
public bool IsTakePhotoVisible => Bytes != null;
public byte[] Bytes { 
    get {return bytes;} 
    set 
    { 
        SetValue(ref bytes, value);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsTakePhotoVisible)); 
    }
}
```

view:

```
set.Bind (btnTakePhoto).For("Visibility").To(x => x.IsTakePhotoVisible).WithConversion("InvertedVisibility");
```

Don't forget to add the Mvvmcross Visibility plugin from nuget, otherwise it won't work ... silently.

Comment: That's not true. `null` is converted to invisible. The converter offers some comfort :) See https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Value-Converters#the-mvx-visibility-valueconverters